# problems Enabling SSL for wordpress

Tags: wordpress, https

I have wordpress installed on an Ubuntu web server. I installed wordpress no problem then followed this guide to add https http://www.liberiangeek.net/2014/10/install-wordpress-self-signed-ssl-apache2-ubuntu-14-04/

my site loads https for the home page and admin page, but all other pages give me a 404 if i try to load them with https.

Maybe i did something wrong along the way but I'm not sure, I've tried following a few guides, editing my wordpress config file to enable ssl, editing the httpaccess file, editing the 000-default.conf and default-ssl.conf but nothing seems to work, it still kills pages like a categories page or a post.

Im not sure if this has anything to do with it but this is an intranet site, and when I set the dns so it has a domain (actually subdomain) it.name.com basically, but whenever i load the site with the domain name it instantly redirects to the IP address, but still loads. also this is a wordpress multisite and I understand somethings are different.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely because you have not installed the [WordPress .htaccess](https://codex.wordpress.org/htaccess) file as required for search engine friendly urls (permalinks). If your using a VPS or DEDICATED server then you will need to ensure that you have mod_rewrite enabled and configured correctly, if your using shared hosting then the likelihood is that it's already enabled.

*Enabling Rewrite*

1. `sudo a2enmod rewrite` - Installs mod_rewrite
2. `sudo service apache2 restart` - Restarts Apache
3. `nano example.conf` Edit your SITE conf file
4. `AllowOverride All` Change none to all

*Creating a WordPress .htaccess file*

In the root path of your website create a blank file called `.htaccess` and fill it with the following WordPress defaults:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```